# What is a "Fa-rer"?

Tags: words, yeshiva-school

Please excuse my somewhat weak "yeshivish". For me, this is a "new" language that seems to be the current Orthodox "parlance", and I'm not that familiar with much of its terminology.

A woman in my neighborhood has a son who will be entering Yeshiva high school next year. She said that as part of the admission process, they asked her son to give something that she thinks sounded like "fah - rer". I had never heard of this term, in the same manner that she hasn't (sometimes I'm glad to find a mom from my "generation" :) But she described it as some type of interview where the principal asks the boy some Gemarah, Halacha and / or Chumash questions and I guess he has to take some Gemara page and explain some section with the commentaries.

I'm guessing this "fah-rer" term (again, I apologize that I probably don't have the correct word) is a Yiddish / yeshivish word? Does anyone know what the correct word / term is, and can you describe exactly what is involved with it? I assume that it has something to do with the admissions interview. If so, and you or someone you know has experienced this, can you recommend how a yeshiva boy should prepare for this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A *FarHer* in "*Yeshivish*" terms means an (usually oral) exam.
It is commonly used when referring to the entry exam given to student applicants before accepting them into a Yeshiva.

From [here](http://www.jewish-languages.org/jewish-english-lexicon/words/1449):

> **Languages of Origin** - Yiddish
>
> **Etymology**
>
> פֿאַרהערן farhérn 'to examine'; פֿאַרהער farhér 'interrogation,
>   hearing; audition'

Comment: Just to note ,it depends what the farher is for. Many times its textual based to see if one can make a laining (read the text inside).

Comment: @sam I meant oral as opposed to written.

Comment: Consider editing in that it comes from the word הערן, to hear

Comment: @Shmuel no need to edit that in. It's already there on the last line under "Etymology". When I got the correct word, I had a feeling that it had something to do with hearing.